# Error in Azure Function v3 .NetCore3.1 Dependency Injection

Tags: azure, dependency-injection, azure-functions

I have been trying to inject DbContext to AzureFunction but I keep on getting the error

> "System.Linq.Expressions: No coercion operator is defined between
> types 'System.Object' and 'System.Void'."

I am using the following packages:

1."Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.0.0"

2. "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.7"

On azure github seems that they created a fix, but I think is not yet merged https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4413

My startup code looks like this:

```
[assembly: FunctionsStartup(typeof(FunctionApp1.Startup))]
namespace FunctionApp1
{
    class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            var SqlConnection = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SqlConnectionString");

            builder.Services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(
                options => options.UseSqlServer(SqlConnection));
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea on a workaround?

Comment: Which packages are you installing? and their versions? I did a quick test, no error occurred.

Comment: Hi, I want to check if you have solved this issue?